# Access Rules on individual pages ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, sitemap, rules

I am using site map for navigation in my website. Is there any way that I could imply access rules on specific pages based on individual user, not on roles based. Each user will have its access right to each page.

I have explored access rules security, its implying on individual user but on folder based, not page based.

I don't want to create new table in database that will have each page path info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `<location>` element in `web.config` to specify users per-page.

```
<configuration>
    <location path="JohnsPage.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="John" />
                <deny users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

This works based from the username the user is logged in as. If you're using integrated windows authentication don't forget you might need to specify the domain too like `<allow users="DOMAIN\John" />`

Comment: dont' want to modify my web config file

Answer (score 1):

You can confugure it in web.config as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <location path="AnyUserPage.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="AnyUser" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: dont' want to modify my web config file

Comment: Well that is a common way. But you can use PrincipalPermissionAttributes something like this: `using System;
using System.Security.Permissions;

[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, User= "SomeUser")]
public class EmployeeManager
{...}` More on topic [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/10/04/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Adding-Authorization-Rules-to-Business-and-Data-Layers-using-PrincipalPermissionAttributes.aspx). If the user is wrong, the ASP.NET runtime throws a security exception which you will have to handle in the global error handler 
(Application_Error).

Comment: But this approach is really inflexible. Why don't you just check the user on Page_Load? If you use Membership: `string userName = User.Identity.Name; if (string.Compare(userName, "SomeUser", true) != 0){Response.Redirect("SomeOtherPage.aspx");} `

Comment: Btw if you change your mind and give a chance to a standard authentication configuration (you do not have to modify your root web.config, you could just put a local web.config into the subfolder with your pages) you may be interested in the [Site-Map Security Trimming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178428.aspx) option which will automatically hide navigational links in a site map, also based on security rules.

Comment: i have already mentioned in my question that Site map trimming works on roles or on particular library not on individual pages. I want to apply security in each user on page based.

Comment: Sorry I haven't noticed anything about Site-Map Trimming in your question text. Anyways Site-Map Trimming relies on the authentication rules which in turn are configured using web.config (either the root one or the local one put into the subfolder). In case you define the authentication rules on per-user and per-page basis like in my answer, the Site-Map Trimming works the same way. You just have to define the same user in Site-Map `<siteMapNode  title="SomePage" description="SomePage" users="SomeUser" url="./SomePage.aspx"/>` after you configured auth rules and allowed trimming in web.config.